# Белая полоса вверху приложения. Как поменять цвет?

Tags: java, android

Пример взял с сайта https://habrahabr.ru/post/270121/
Ссылка на исходник готового приложения https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

Исходник полностью скопировал, но сверху появилось белая полоса. Не могу понять, как поменять цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в CoordinatorLayout добавить

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

То цвет остается, но в этом случае, вверх прокручивается, и наверху видна часть изображения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя вверх должен оставаться на месте и изображение, должно проходить под ним

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходник:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    tools:context="net.artsait.slideimg.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="@string/quila_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/quila_tagline"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:contentPadding="16dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/quila_name2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/quila"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="net.artsait.slideimg.AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно у вас `statusBar` прозрачный, попробуйте изменить его цвет:

**Работает на Api level >= 21**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.youtBackgroundColor));
}
```

Comment: Может я что-то не так понял? Код я записал в onCreate
Перед кодом записал MainActivity activity; Сейчас в первой строке подчеркивает красным activity и в последней setStatusBarColor

Comment: Если навести на setStatusBarColor то попокажет
Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.view.Window#setStatusBarColor

Comment: замените на getApplicationContext()

Comment: ааа да, это работает на api level >= 21

Comment: api level? Пока мне это не о чем не говорить)) Я так понял у меня это не сработает?

Comment: Немного подредактировал, заработало спасибо Вам

Comment: в смысле версия Android'a на вашем устройстве. Т.е. если данный код будет работать на версиях Android'a начиная с 5.0 (Android Lollipop) и выше. Если у вас в build.gradle minTargetVersion = меньше 21 (Android 5.0  Lollipop ) - то AndroidStudio может ругаться, но все равно она должна компилировать код, просто работать будет только на 5 Андроиде

Answer (score 1):

Решения нашел, заодно можно и цвет навигации поменять

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```